# Getting Error: [$parse:syntax] while using ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing custom form validation, using ng-class to highlight required field, the syntax is:

```
<div class="form-group"
    ng-class="{'has-error': dc.{{fname}}.nedatt({{fname}}.username)}">
    <input class="form-control" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username"
           ng-required="true" ng-model="f1username"/>
           <span class="help-block" ng-show="{{fname}}.username.$error.required">Required</span>
</div>
```

For ng-class I am getting:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax]                  
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.3/$parse/syntax?p0=.&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=1&p3=.username.%24error.required&p4=.username.%24error.required
```

For help block am getting:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

Actually `fname` is name of form to be replaced so am using inside `{{}}`. Please help, I am stuck.

Comment: You'd better post your js code. : )

Comment: @Tyler.z.yang its throwing this error in console am not able to find why.. its official code so i pasted only part of it.. with this can u help

Comment: What's in `dc`? My understanding is that `fname` is the name of the form that this particular component will be applied; instead it should actually point to a form object.

Comment: @raina77ow its an object it contains formname as a key, so am passing fname to dc.

Comment: @user2210579 In angularjs '{{}}' tells Angular to replace the text content. But in angular directive like 'ng-show' you cannot add '{{}}' this into it. Can you tell me what is {{fname}} means? If fname is a key in $scope then you can use 'fname' instead.

Comment: From where do you get the name of the form? Is it written in HTML directly (i.e., `<form name="fname">...` before the code shown)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not bind an angular expression in ng-class like that. You should use javascript notation instead. That means:

```
<div class="form-group"
    ng-class="{'has-error': dc[fname].nedatt(getFormObject(fname).name)">
</div>
```

It looks that you are trying to dynamize the object that you use to check the name property. Unfortunately you can't do it like this, the object "must" be fixed, not a string. For that reason I would suggest calling a function in your controller or directive that returns the right object, and then, do whatever you need with it.

For the ng-show I would implement something similar. Just keep in mind that it will not be string-parsed, but directly evaluated (and in javascript {{foo}} is not right syntax)

Comment: thanks it worked. but still i have doubt internally {{fname}} will convert to a string representation but i have already have an formobj defined in same name which fname equals to

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean. If you feel that creating a fiddle can help me understand, please do it.